# Defining maximum container size [boostrap 5]

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap 5 and am missing a super basic concept...how do I make it so my container can't expand past a maximum width? I don't want the container larger than 1040px.

Using a `style="max-width:1170"` type of CSS breaks the primary navigation.

Here is the code I am trying to make work: https://codepen.io/asl-dfjk/pen/qBmQxQj

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in your codepen inline styling. Check `<div class="container" style="max-width: 1040px;>` and change it to `<div class="container" style="max-width: 1040px;">`.

Changing the max-width property should work as expected.

Comment: I guess you can also use `<div class="container-md">` to make the maximum width of the container to be equal to the md breakpoint as well - so kinda cool!